# tkinter - tk.Stringvar() Attribute Error

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

My code follows. The part we're concerned with is "labelText = tk.Stringvar()" in the Page frame.

It throws the following error:
"AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Stringvar'"

Why does it throw an error? How would I prevent this error?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Program(tk.Tk):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default = "")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Page, Other):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Page)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        innerFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg="red")
        innerFrame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c", relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)

        labelText = tk.Stringvar()

class Other(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

app = Program()
app.state('zoomed')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should have looked up the list of legal tkinter attributes yourself: `import tkinter; print(dir(tkinter))`.  Or in IDLE or other IDE with name completion: `import tkinter as tk` followed by `>>> tk.` followed by wait or whatever invokes completions followed by popup box.  Type `S` and `StringVar` is highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tkinter has no attribute `Stringvar` You should replace it with `StringVar`.

```
labelText = tk.StringVar()
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `Stringvar()` with `StringVar()`. The "var" needs to be capitalized.